# How to ask a question from server to client in restfull webservice?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I am writing a program using jersey implementation in rest API for trading application, currently I am passing the stock name in URL, but if I want to ask the client which stock do you want? and client should answer then fetching corresponding stock details from database by server. How to do this? Kindly help me I am new to this field.

```
@Path("/stock")
public class stock {
    @POST
    @Path("/dostock")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String doStock(@QueryParam("SymbolName") String SymbolName) throws Exception {
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        
        
        obj2=checkStock(SymbolName);
        System.out.println(obj2.toString());
        
        if(obj2.toString()!=null) {
            return obj2.toString();
        }
        
        else {
            String resp="";
            resp="true"+Utility.constructJSON("Fail", false);
            return resp;
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Would you provide some example and elaborate your use-case please?

Comment: now I am specifying like this http://localhost:8080/userauthentication_stock/webapi/stock/dostock?SymbolName=ODP    I.e SymbolName is specifying in url, but I dont want to specify it in URL. I want to ask a a question from server, "which stock do you want?" and client (I am using postman) should answer ODP @VIJAYKUMARSUBRAMANI

Comment: Use event source or WebSocket. If you use a library, you may use socket.io.